# Somebody send e_mail to US embassy presenting to be me , Can I find him?

Tags: visas, usa, legal, communication, fraud

I recently find out that somebody has sent so many e_mail to US embassy in Germany and present himself as me and changed my appointment for visa interview , Can I follow it legally or find him or not?

Comment: Have you contacted the authorities? I would have to imagine that identity theft would be treated seriously in Germany, which is very particular about privacy and identity issues.

Comment: Why not contact the embassy directly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email fraud.

Comment: Be sure to inform the US embassy **directly** about this problem, as they will be very interested to avoid granting a visa to the wrong person.

Answer (score 4):

File a criminal charge against an unknown person with the country authorities. Germans DO take those things seriously.

Comment: Even more important, with a written documentation of the filing, it is much easier to convince the embassy that this actually happened, so that they will ignore that an earlier appointment has been missed (if they care about that at all during the process - since the appointments cost some fee, they might not care).